# window.open(url, '_blank') open two window from backend

Tags: jsf-2

I have made this code in backend JSF

```
 public void goToURL(String url) {
        RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("window.open(' " + url + "', '_blank').focus()");
    }

<f:actionListener  binding="#{bean.goToURL('/myPage.xhtml')}"/>
```

but whene i call it from my page xhtml, it oppned two tab after one click